# Laravel 5.7 validation using required_with and required_with_all for 3 fields does not work

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-request

My question is how does logics using `required_with` and `required_with_all` for Laravel validation works?

I have read the documentation but can not get anything from it [documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-required-with-all)

I am applying for 3 different fields

Let me give you my example now to get what I want

```
'start' => 'nullable|required_with:end',
'end' => 'nullable|required_with:start',
'repeat' => 'nullable|required_with_all:start,end',
```

if I just submit with only repeat field no validation is performed in Laravel.

You can remove nullable is from the code I copied from, still no validation is performed if you provide only repeat field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP actually wanted here is:

1. Being able to submit start and end without repeat being present
2. Start and end are required together
3. Not being able to submit repeat if start or end are present

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
    ...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'start' => 'required_with:end|required_without:repeat',
          'end' => 'required_with:start|required_without:repeat',
          'repeat' => 'required_without_all:start,end',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            if ((!$this->input('start') || !$this->input('end')) && $this->input('repeat')) {
                $validator->errors()->add('repeat', 'The repeat field is required when start and end are present.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Idea. But this will not solve the problem since you have to provide repeat when start and end is present which is quite opposite.

Comment: Being able to submit start and end without repeat being present and not able to submit repeat only when both start and end are not present

Comment: I see that so I think I have to work around things on my own to achieve what I want right?

Comment: I am using form request

Comment: Just added same concept but I made it through Controller

Comment: @ReubenWedson If the concept solved your issue, please accept the answer. :)